# Program for counting identical bits in 2 hex values in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, binary, hex, converters

I am new to programming in Swift and my task is to create a program that will return a number of identical **bits** in 2 hexadecimal values. I wrote something like this:

```
let str = "8ef4b5013e183e12eab15dc28eb3de29"
var hexAr = Array(str)
let str2 = "b19d3fa46038d6bd1d7ae5e915fb68b3"
var hex2Ar = Array(str2)
let result = 0

for i in hexAr {
  //conversion to binary...
  for i in binAr {
   if binAr[i] == bin2Ar[i]
    {result++}
  }
}
```

Now, I found a method that converts hex value to array with binary representation:

```
let hexValue = 0x5
let bin = String(hexValue, radix:2) //output: 101
let binArray = Array(bin) // output: [1,0,1]
```

The problem of the above-mentioned method is that it returns 101, not 0101, for which I need to compare identical bits in both hex values. Then, comparing 5 (0101) and D (1101) will add 3 to the result.

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Instead of traversing through all bits you can simply logically AND the two values and count the `1` bits of the result.

Comment: @zisoft: You probably mean XOR ?

Comment: @MartinR: By further thinking about it... *identical*  bits means both bits are `1` OR both bits are `0`. This indeed cannot be solved by AND. And by XOR neither... There are two comparisons necessary: First by ANDing both values, then inverting both values and again ANDing.

Comment: @zisoft: No, only XOR is needed, then count the 0 bits.

Comment: @MartinR: Got it, you are right!

Comment: It's the equivalence operator f(a,a) = 1, f(a, b) = 0 where b != a. Equivalence is the same as `NOT XOR`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equality

Comment: @zisoft thanks for the tip, but how do I XOR two character arrays? Compiler returns an error "Cannot invoke '^' with an argument list of type '($T10, IntegerLiteralConvertible)' "

The code I try is:
 if (hexAr[i] ^ hex2Ar[i] == 0)
   {...}

Comment: Also, how do I count the 0 bits after XORing?